# Is there any relation between pragma and predefined macros in C programming language, using GCC or any other compiler?

Tags: c, gcc, macros, pragma

Recently I was asked if I know what pragma and macro is, and since I had used `#pragma` directive, I answered yes. But when I failed to implement a predefined macro (`-Dsome_macro` in gcc command arguments to define the macro `some_macro`) I was told that it is because I do not know what pragma is!

I know that in C and C++ it is possible to define a macro which contains `pragma` keyword in it, and I think it is not relevant to this situation. I looked up features of `#pragma` and I was not able to find any thing related to predefined macros. So I was wondering if they were referring to another type of pragma or another concept in programming for it.

Sorry for the vague question, but is there any relation between pragma and macro in c programming language according to what I described?

---

Edit:

OK, I finally asked the person directly and it turned out that it was just a misunderstanding. And by pragma he simply meant the `#pragma` directive and there was no relation between it and the macro.

Thanks to every one who responded and sorry for the confusing question.

Comment: "_I know that in C and C++ it is possible to define a macro which contains pragma keyword in it,_": `pragma` is not a keyword. You can use it like any other identifier. It only has special meaning when following `#` in a preprocessor directive.

Comment: @user17732522 I simply did not do that, I was supposed to add a predefined macro but I forgot to do that and the program did not compile as desired, as the result. I am clueless my self on how can a predefined macro be related to pragma. again sorry for the vague question

Comment: "_I looked up features of #pragma and I was not able to find any thing related to predefined macros._": What `#pragma` does is completely implementation-defined and dependent on the specific compiler. That is the purpose of it. If you are looking for some `#pragma` syntax allowed by GCC specifically which is related to macros, see e.g. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Push_002fPop-Macro-Pragmas.html#Push_002fPop-Macro-Pragmas.

Comment: But, I don't think i have actually seen that specific GCC pragma being used. Since it is for MSVC-compatibility that might be different in the Windows world.

Comment: @user17732522 thank you that is an interesting feature. maybe that was what they were referring to. I should ask them about it. But at this point, I am really wondering, maybe there is other concept which is called pragma

Comment: I see, I misread that first quote. Using `-D...` on the command line to define a macro makes sense e.g. in a build system. If it is something internal to the code, e.g. a constant, then it should be defined with `#define` inside the code. But that doesn't have anything to do with `#pragma` either.

Comment: @user17732522 yes I agree, as far as I know that is true. I should really go and ask them directly. I was just wondering maybe I am missing something. Thank you very much for your responses.

Comment: @user17732522 BTW, do you think I should put this question on hold or delete it for now?

Comment: Do whatever you want with the question. I don't know how I could give it a clear answer. If others think the same they will vote to close it. If someone thinks they can write a helpful answer, they might.

Comment: Pragmas and (pre-defined) macros are separate concepts.  There is almost no overlap between them.  The only possible overlap is if/when you use the `_Pragma` operator in the body of a macro.

Comment: This is why I don't usually ask if someone "knows" something. Instead I ask them to explain to me in 2 or 3 sentences what they know about it.

Comment: Specifying `-Dsome_macro` is not specifying a pre-defined macro.  Pretty much by definition, a pre-defined macro is defined without you taking any action.  I'm confused by the assertion that you don't understand pragmas because you didn't define a (user-defined) macro on the command line.  There'd have to be a lot more context given to make that claim plausible.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formal definition of predefined macros (C17 6.10.8) are things like `__STDC__` which are specified by the compiler and/or standard libraries rather than the application programmer.

`-D` is a special gcc feature to define macros at compile-time - I guess you could call those "pre-defined" if you like but I don't think that's a (de facto) standard definition of the term.

`#pragma` is generally used whenever a compiler wants to use an implementation-defined feature but without having that feature collide with other compilers. A compiler which doesn't recognize a pragma should ignore it.

There are a very special case `#pragma` specified by the C standard such as `#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS` coming with the floating point environment `fenv.h` header. I guess these are somewhat similar to predefined macros, but this is such a specialized use that I wouldn't expect the average programmer to know anything about it. Personally, I barely ever used `fenv.h`. Other than these rare `STDC` pragmas, there's no obvious relation between pragmas and predefined macros.

As of C99, C has the `_Pragma` operator which is also a special snowflake barely ever used, the purpose is indeed to enable pragmas inside function-like macros.

None of the most common uses of pragmas have anything to do with function-like macros or pre-defined macros though.
I'd say the most common use of pragmas encountered by the average programmer is certain semi-portable ones like `#pragma pack()` used to set struct padding/alignment. Or to enable/disable compiler warnings locally, such as this:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wpedantic"
int arr[0];
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

Similarly, this could have been written as a function-like macro with the `_Pragma`operator:

```
#define declare_skunky_array(name)                 \
  _Pragma("GCC diagnostic push")                   \
  _Pragma("GCC diagnostic ignored \"-Wpedantic\"") \
  int name[0];                                     \
  _Pragma("GCC diagnostic pop")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I asked the person about it and I have updated my question accordingly.